# Save my emails in files

Tags: files, email

So as said in the title, i want to find a way download my emails on my pc and save them in a file. ( so then i could use linux text manipulation commands on them to do some filtering )

i'v found "mutt" a text-based e-mail client, and configured it to log into my GMail inbox. But first, it seems like it doesn't get all my emails. And then, I didn't find a way to save the emails i get in a file.

So if anyone knows any way of doing it, please make me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When accessing the emails in Gmail it takes some time to download and sometimes Google will kick you out and you need to reconnect. If you make to many requests it may even quick you out for a full day.

You can use Thunderbird to download the messages. It archives the emails in [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format. Here's the part you are going to love:

> All messages in an mbox mailbox are concatenated and stored as plain text in a single file. The beginning of each message is indicated by a line whose first five characters consist of "From" followed by a space (the so named "From_ line" or "'From ' line" or simply "From line") and the return path e-mail address. A blank line is appended to the end of each message

Thunderbird does use a slightly modified version ([more info here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Importing_and_exporting_your_mail#Mbox_files).)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Oh yeah !! That's it. Thank you very much dude. I just need to find a way to make thunderbird download my mails automatically.

Comment: Thunderbird should do it, but you may have to relaunch the download.